# Display activity indicator

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a activity indicator in swift but some how it is not showing it self why so ever .. activity indicator is on a view

So what I do: 
    Starting the activity indicator in the view did load

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.activityPanelOn(true)
}
```

How I create the indicator / animated it

```
 func activityPanelOn(on: Bool){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations:  {() in
            self.actvityPanel.alpha = 0
            }, completion:{(finished: Bool)  in
                if(finished){
                    self.actvityPanel.hidden = !on
                }
        });
    }
```

And here is where i want to stop it

```
 func getDateFromJSON(){
        //Calling the method getTabelData from RestParser
        RestParser.sharedInstance.getTableData{json in
            //iterating to the JSON file to get alle data
            let results = json
            for (index: String,tabelData:JSON)in results{
                self.items.append(tabelData)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                //if O.K reload TableView
                **self.activityPanelOn(false)**
                self.tableview.reloadData()

            })

            println(json)
        }
    }
```

But the indicator is never shown why ?

Comment: Maybe you need `self.actvityPanel.alpha = on ? 1.0 : 0.0`?

Comment: @Antonio that did thx ! want to post it as a answer '?

Comment: It looks like @vadian gave the same solution at the same time... but as an answer and not a comment - just mark his as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the alpha value is always set to 0.0 in the animation block.

Try

```
self.actvityPanel.alpha = (on) ? 1.0 : 0.0
```